# Extracting file name with spaces using awk

Tags: awk

I have this line of output:

`M file.txt`

Getting fed into this awk program:

`awk '{printf("\t%s: %s %s\n", FNR, $1, $2)}'`

which returns

`1: M file.txt`

This works and is the usual case. However, if the file has spaces and the line of output looks something like this:

`M "tmux split-window subcommand.md"`

awk gives give this:

`1: M "tmux`

But the desired output is this:

`1: M "tmux split-window subcommand.md"`

How can I fix this?

Comment: What's your end goal here? if you just want to number your output lines, piping to `nl` or `cat -n` would be simpler. If you insist on using awk, you could print the whole record e.g. `'{printf("\t%s: %s\n", FNR, $0)}'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a delimiter, it will not consider the spaces in between your quotations as separate words.

So we can use any delimiter that you feel will not show up in your input string.

`echo 'M "tmux split-window subcommand.md"' | awk -F: '{printf("\t%s: %s %s\n", FNR, $1, $2)}'
        1: M "tmux split-window subcommand.md"`

Comment: This seems to be just an obfuscated way of printing `$0` (since if the record doesn't contain the chosen delimiter, `$1` equals `$0` and `$2` is empty)

Answer (score 2):

To prepend the line number to the current line using `awk`:

```
awk '{ printf("%d: %s\n", FNR, $0) }'
```

The zeroth field, `$0`, is the complete line.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  #!/usr/bin/awk -f
  BEGIN {
        #FPAT = "([^,]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")" # seperator is ,
        #FPAT = "([^,]*)|(\"[^\"]*\")" # seperator is , and allow empty field -> notice the "+" changed to "*"
        FPAT = "([^ ]+)|(\"[^\"]*\")" # seperator is <space> -> notice the "," changed to " "
  }
  {
    printf("%d: ", FNR);
        for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
            printf("%s ", $i)
        }
    printf("\n");
  }
```

I got it from GNU awk's online manual. Here is it.  https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html